# how to use MongoDB mapReduce function in Meteor javascript file?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mapreduce

I am currently working on GeoSpatial project which I am using MongoDB as database and Meteor for creating my app. I have run some query(with mapReduce) in MongoDB on spatial data and I want to put this code(query) on Meteor (javascript file). I did some research on that but still i have problem. I don't know how to write mapReduce function in meteor.

here is my mapReduce code in MongoDB:

```
var map1 = function() {

var px =-83.215;
var py =41.53;

if(this.geometry.minlon<=px && px<=this.geometry.maxlon && this.geometry.minlat<=py && py<=this.geometry.maxlat)    
{emit(this._id, 1);}

}

var reduce1 = function(key, value) {
return Array.sum(value)
}

db.C1DB.mapReduce(map1, reduce1, {
out: "CollectionName"
})
```

Comment: Look at the [monbro:mongodb-mapreduce-aggregation](https://atmospherejs.com/monbro/mongodb-mapreduce-aggregation) package

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you can do it in 2 similar ways:

- using [package](https://atmospherejs.com/monbro/mongodb-mapreduce-aggregation) mentioned in comments above.
- or using [Raw Collection API](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-rawCollection) which mentioned package uses.

Here's working example how to do it without package:

```
C1DB = new Mongo.Collection('c1db');
CollectionName = new Mongo.Collection('CollectionName');

Meteor.methods({
    doMapReduce: function () {
        var mapFn = function () {
            var px = -83.215;
            var py = 41.53;

            if (this.geometry.minlon <= px && px <= this.geometry.maxlon && this.geometry.minlat <= py && py <= this.geometry.maxlat) {
                emit(this._id, 1);
            }
        };

        var reduceFn = function (key, value) {
            return Array.sum(value)
        };

        var rawC1DB = C1DB.rawCollection();

        // convert mapReduce to synchronous function
        var syncMapReduce = Meteor.wrapAsync(rawC1DB.mapReduce, rawC1DB);

        // CollectionName will be overwritten after each mapReduce call
        syncMapReduce(mapFn, reduceFn, {
            out: "CollectionName"
        });

        return CollectionName.find({}).fetch();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! it works! I am just wondering why we need to convert mapReduce to synchronous function. Also I did some research about rawCollection function but I am still confuse about its role.

Comment: You need `wrapAsync` in case if you would like to return reduced result from Meteor's method. It is impossible to return method result from callback though (in case without `wrapAsync`).

Comment: Meteor's `Mongo.Collection` doesn't support `mapReduce` method, that's why I am using `rawCollection` in order to get plain Mongo DB collection. By the way, if this answer works for you, mark it as correct answer, so it will be useful other people with similar problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

There's also, now a cleaner package to expose this functionality.

https://github.com/fentas/meteor-mapreduce

It appears to be a fork of `meteorhacks:aggregate` package, which is excellent.